# Eclipse import external JAR via system variable

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar

i wish to add external JAR to my project without using Eclipse GUI. i have a system variable which hold the absolute path to the JAR file, how may i add it using java code.

Comment: you want to use the jar knowing only it absolute path ?

Comment: @FGraviton i only know that some environment variable of my OS holds the absolute path to the JAR file

Comment: Is this for use within eclipse, or at the command line (which the current answers cover)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the classpath variable then all other programs for which you dont specify a classpath while compiling or executing will assume the same classpath. This will result in an issue one way or the other. Like Snicolas said, its a very static way of doing things.

Instead what I would suggest is, if you have a variable like JAR_PATH set in your OS, then use the variable itself as below:

```
Windows:  java -classpath %JAR_PATH%;<other elements of your classpath> mainclass
Unix: java -classpath $JAR_PATH:<other elements of your classpath> mainclass
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean use it for compilation, or use it at run time ?

If you want to do both, you can set the CLASSPATH environment variable and the jar to it. Otherwise you could add it to your command lines for javac or java using the -classpath command line switch.

And if you want to deploy your app using this jar, then you must follow [this guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) to add the jar path to the manifest

Comment: thanks you for your reply. i want to add it for compilation and execution. will the classpath system enrionment will do?

Comment: yes, but it's a very static way to do things. But yes it will.

Comment: it is surely strange, since my classpath already includes the absolute path to the JAR file